# is it possible to make a html div with a animation and a hover scale?

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, css-animations

I tried making divs as buttons that link to another subpage. I animated them so they rotate in when going on the site. Now I want to make a hover effect that scales the buttons. But it seems like it doesn´t get recognized. When I comment the animaton out it works. Is there a way to have the animation and the hover effect?

Thanks in advance!

```
.animation-links div {
  background: #444;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}
#animation-1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #03a9f4, #f441a5, #ffeb3b, #03a9f4);
  background-size: 400%;
  animation-name: animated;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
} animation-delay: 0.5s;


@keyframes animated {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
}
}

.animation-links div:hover {
    transform: scale(1.10);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

If the value for `animation-fill-mode` is not none then when animation ends it will not apply the css property values.

So I have removed `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` from `#animation-1` style rule and `transform: rotateY(90deg);` from `.animation-links div` style rule. Also there were some extra `{` and style set outside the braces. I have removed those as well.

See the Snippet below:

```css
.animation-links div {
  background: #444;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  transform-origin: center;
}
#animation-1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #03a9f4, #f441a5, #ffeb3b, #03a9f4);
  background-size: 400%;
  animation-name: animated;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  /*animation-fill-mode: forwards;*/
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}


@keyframes animated {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
}

.animation-links div:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
```

```html
<div class="animation-links">
  <div id="animation-1">Animation 1</div>
</div>
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/Ljmxvb0t/) also.